# Unable to Resize Linux Install Partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm using an Acer Nitro 5 (AN515-54-51M5) laptop, dual booting Windows 10 and Kubuntu 20.04.
I installed Kubuntu on a 43 GB partition on the same SSD that Windows is installed on, and now I would like to shrink it as I do not need that much space dedicated to Linux.
I created a GParted Live USB and attempted to use it to shrink the EXT4 partition that Linux is installed on (By 10 gigabytes, there are about 25 free on the partition). However, it failed to do so, telling me that first, I needed to run the command:
`e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p5`.
I ran the command in the GParted terminal (with sudo) and on Pass 5 (Checking group summary information) it returned:
`/dev/nvme0n1p5: 279216/2859008 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 4390101/11430656 blocks`
I assume that the "non-contiguous" files are preventing me from shrinking the partition. How do I solve this?

Comment: Show me a screenshot of `gparted`. I assume that you wish to add the reclaimed space to the Windows partition?

Comment: Image of gparted: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuOtaPifuPoB9wF68l-xhtR2QqJO

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, however, I don't need to see the errors so much, but rather, the main `gparted` window that shows me how your disk is partitioned. I also needed to hear where you plan on using the reclaimed space... add it back to the Windows C: drive, or elsewhere?

Comment: I plan to add the reclaimed space back to the Windows C: drive, yes.

Comment: I'm still waiting to see your updated `gparted` screenshot, as per my previous comment`. Use imgur.com to save your image.